# C++20 : N-dimensional minimal Matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, c++20

I wrote a N-dim matrix (tensor) class, based on my previous 2D matrix implementation([2D Matrix in C++20 and Strassen's algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253908/2d-matrix-in-c20-and-strassens-algorithm)), accepting many helpful reviews from here.

MatrixBase.h

```
#ifndef FROZENCA_MATRIXBASE_H
#define FROZENCA_MATRIXBASE_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include "MatrixUtils.h"
#include "MatrixInitializer.h"

namespace frozenca {

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
class MatrixBase {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t ndim = N;

private:
    std::size_t size_;
    std::array<std::size_t, N> dims_;
    std::array<std::size_t, N> strides_;

protected:
    MatrixBase() = delete;
    virtual ~MatrixBase() = default;

    template <typename... Dims>
    explicit MatrixBase(Dims... dims);

    MatrixBase(std::size_t size,
               const std::array<std::size_t, N> dims,
               const std::array<std::size_t, N> strides) : size_ {size}, dims_ {dims}, strides_ {strides} {}

public:
    using value_type = R;
    using reference = R&;
    using const_reference = const R&;
    using pointer = R*;

    friend void swap(MatrixBase& a, MatrixBase& b) noexcept {
        std::swap(a.size_, b.size_);
        std::swap(a.dims_, b.dims_);
        std::swap(a.strides_, b.strides_);
    }

    auto begin() { return static_cast<T&>(*this).begin(); }
    auto cbegin() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this).cbegin(); }
    auto end() { return static_cast<T&>(*this).end(); }
    auto cend() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this).cend(); }
    auto rbegin() { return static_cast<T&>(*this).rbegin(); }
    auto crbegin() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this).crbegin(); }
    auto rend() { return static_cast<T&>(*this).rend(); }
    auto crend() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this).crend(); }

    template <RequestingElement... Args>
    reference operator()(Args... args);

    template <RequestingElement... Args>
    const_reference operator()(Args... args) const;

    reference operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos);
    const_reference operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos) const;

    template <std::regular U>
    MatrixBase(std::initializer_list<U>) = delete;

    template <std::regular U>
    MatrixBase& operator=(std::initializer_list<U>) = delete;

    MatrixBase(typename MatrixInitializer<R, N>::type init);

    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t size() const { return size_;}

    [[nodiscard]] const std::array<std::size_t, N>& dims() const {
        return dims_;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t dims(std::size_t n) const {
        if (n >= N) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range in dims");
        }
        return dims_[n];
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const std::array<std::size_t, N>& strides() const {
        return strides_;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t strides(std::size_t n) const {
        if (n >= N) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range in strides");
        }
        return strides_[n];
    }

};

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
template <typename... Dims>
MatrixBase<T, R, N>::MatrixBase(Dims... dims) : size_{(... * static_cast<std::size_t>(dims))},
    dims_{static_cast<std::size_t>(dims)...} {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Dims) == N);
    if (std::ranges::find(dims_, 0lu) != std::end(dims_)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Zero dimension not allowed");
    }
    strides_ = computeStrides(dims_);
}

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
MatrixBase<T, R, N>::MatrixBase(typename MatrixInitializer<R, N>::type init) {
    dims_ = deriveDims<N>(init);
    strides_ = computeStrides(dims_);
    size_ = strides_[0] * dims_[0];
}

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
template <RequestingElement... Args>
typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::reference MatrixBase<T, R, N>::operator()(Args... args) {
    return const_cast<typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::reference>(std::as_const(*this).operator()(args...));
}

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
template <RequestingElement... Args>
typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::const_reference MatrixBase<T, R, N>::operator()(Args... args) const {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N);
    std::array<std::size_t, N> pos {std::size_t(args)...};
    return this->operator[](pos);
}

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::reference MatrixBase<T, R, N>::operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos) {
    return const_cast<typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::reference>(std::as_const(*this).operator[](pos));
}

template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
typename MatrixBase<T, R, N>::const_reference MatrixBase<T, R, N>::operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos) const {
    if (!std::equal(std::cbegin(pos), std::cend(pos), std::cbegin(dims_), std::less<>{})) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of range in element access");
    }
    return *(cbegin() + std::inner_product(std::cbegin(pos), std::cend(pos), std::cbegin(strides_), 0lu));
}

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //FROZENCA_MATRIXBASE_H
```

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef FROZENCA_MATRIX_H
#define FROZENCA_MATRIX_H

#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include "MatrixBase.h"
#include "MatrixView.h"
#include "MatrixInitializer.h"

namespace frozenca {

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
class Matrix final : public MatrixBase<Matrix<T, N>, T, N> {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;

public:
    using Base = MatrixBase<Matrix<T, N>, T, N>;
    using Base::size;
    using Base::dims;
    using Base::strides;

    template <typename... Dims>
    explicit Matrix(Dims... dims);

    ~Matrix() override = default;

    friend void swap(Matrix& a, Matrix& b) noexcept {
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
        std::swap(a.data_, b.data_);
    }

    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    iterator begin() { return &data_[0];}
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return &data_[0]; }
    iterator end() { return &data_[size()];}
    const_iterator cend() const { return &data_[size()];}
    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());}
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cend());}
    reverse_iterator rend() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());}
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cbegin());}

    template <typename M, std::regular U>
    Matrix(const MatrixBase<M, U, N>&);

    template <typename M, std::regular U>
    Matrix& operator=(const MatrixBase<M, U, N>&);

    Matrix(typename MatrixInitializer<T, N>::type init);
    Matrix& operator=(typename MatrixInitializer<T, N>::type init);

    MatrixView<T, N> submatrix(const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos_begin, const std::array<std::size_t, N>& pos_end = dims()) {
        if (!std::equal(std::cbegin(pos_begin), std::cend(pos_begin), std::cbegin(pos_end), std::less<>{})) {
            throw std::out_of_range("submatrix begin/end position error");
        }
        std::array<std::size_t, N> view_dims;
        std::transform(std::cbegin(pos_end), std::cend(pos_end), std::cbegin(pos_begin), std::begin(view_dims), std::minus<>{});
        std::size_t view_size = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(view_dims), std::cend(view_dims), 1lu, std::multiplies<>{});
        MatrixView<T, N> view (view_size, view_dims, strides(), &this->operator[](pos_begin));
        return view;
    }
};

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
template <typename... Dims>
Matrix<T, N>::Matrix(Dims... dims) : Base(dims...), data_(std::make_unique<T[]>(size())) {
}

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
Matrix<T, N>::Matrix(typename MatrixInitializer<T, N>::type init) : Base(init),
        data_(std::make_unique<T[]>(size())) {
    insertFlat(data_, init);
}

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
Matrix<T, N>& Matrix<T, N>::operator=(typename MatrixInitializer<T, N>::type init) {
    Matrix<T, N> mat(init);
    swap(*this, mat);
    return *this;
}

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //FROZENCA_MATRIX_H
```

MatrixView.h

```
#ifndef FROZENCA_MATRIXVIEW_H
#define FROZENCA_MATRIXVIEW_H

#include <compare>
#include "MatrixBase.h"

namespace frozenca {

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
class MatrixView final : public MatrixBase<MatrixView<T, N>, T, N> {
private:
    T* data_view_;
    std::array<std::size_t, N> view_strides_;

public:
    using Base = MatrixBase<MatrixView<T, N>, T, N>;
    using Base::size;
    using Base::dims;
    using Base::strides;

    explicit MatrixView(std::size_t size,
                        const std::array<std::size_t, N>& dims,
                        const std::array<std::size_t, N>& strides,
                        T* data_view) : Base(size, dims, strides), data_view_ {data_view} {
        view_strides_ = computeStrides(dims);
    }

    ~MatrixView() override = default;

    friend void swap(MatrixView& a, MatrixView& b) noexcept {
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
        std::swap(a.data_view_, b.data_view_);
        std::swap(a.view_strides_, b.view_strides_);
    }

    template <typename T_>
    struct MVIterator {
        MatrixView* ptr_ = nullptr;
        std::array<std::size_t, N> pos_ = {0};
        std::size_t offset_ = 0;
        std::size_t index_ = 0;

        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T_;
        using pointer = T_*;
        using reference = T_&;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

        MVIterator(MatrixView* ptr, std::array<std::size_t, N> pos = {0}) : ptr_ {ptr}, pos_ {pos} {
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        reference operator*() const {
            return ptr_->data_view_[offset_];
        }

        pointer operator->() const {
            return ptr_->data_view_ + offset_;
        }

        void ValidateOffset() {
            offset_ = std::inner_product(std::cbegin(pos_), std::cend(pos_), std::cbegin(ptr_->strides()), 0lu);
            index_ = std::inner_product(std::cbegin(pos_), std::cend(pos_), std::cbegin(ptr_->view_strides_), 0lu);
            if (index_ > ptr_->size()) {
                throw std::out_of_range("MatrixView iterator out of range");
            }
        }

        void Increment() {
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                ++pos_[i];
                if (pos_[i] != ptr_->dims(i) || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    pos_[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Increment(std::ptrdiff_t n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                Decrement(-n);
                return;
            }
            auto carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(n);
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                std::size_t curr_dim = ptr_->dims(i);
                pos_[i] += carry;
                if (pos_[i] < curr_dim || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    carry = pos_[i] / curr_dim;
                    pos_[i] %= curr_dim;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Decrement() {
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                --pos_[i];
                if (pos_[i] != static_cast<std::size_t>(-1) || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    pos_[i] = ptr_->dims(i) - 1;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Decrement(std::ptrdiff_t n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                Increment(-n);
                return;
            }
            auto carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(n);
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                std::size_t curr_dim = ptr_->dims(i);
                pos_[i] -= carry;
                if (pos_[i] < curr_dim || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(-quot(static_cast<long>(pos_[i]), static_cast<long>(curr_dim)));
                    pos_[i] = mod(static_cast<long>(pos_[i]), static_cast<long>(curr_dim));
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        MVIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator++(int) {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator--(int) {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator operator+(difference_type n) const {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            temp.Increment(n);
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator+=(difference_type n) {
            Increment(n);
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator-(difference_type n) const {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            temp.Decrement(n);
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator-=(difference_type n) {
            Decrement(n);
            return *this;
        }

        reference operator[](difference_type n) const {
            return *(this + n);
        }

        template <typename T2>
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T_>, std::remove_cv_t<T2>>, difference_type>
                operator-(const MVIterator<T2>& other) const {
            return offset_ - other.offset_;
        }

        // oh no.. *why* defining operator<=> doesn't work to automatically define these in gcc?
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T1>, std::remove_cv_t<T2>>,
                bool>
        operator==(const MVIterator<T1>& it1, const MVIterator<T2>& it2) {
            return it1.offset_ == it2.offset_;
        }

        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T1>, std::remove_cv_t<T2>>,
                bool>
        operator!=(const MVIterator<T1>& it1, const MVIterator<T2>& it2) {
            return !(it1 == it2);
        }

        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T1>, std::remove_cv_t<T2>>,
        std::compare_three_way_result_t<std::size_t, std::size_t>>
        operator<=>(const MVIterator<T1>& it1, const MVIterator<T2>& it2) {
            return it1.offset_ <=> it2.offset_;
        }
    };

    using iterator = MVIterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = MVIterator<const T>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    iterator begin() { return iterator(this);}
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(this, {dims(0), });}
    const_iterator cend() const { return iterator(this, {dims(0), });}
    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());}
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cend());}
    reverse_iterator rend() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());}
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cbegin());}

};

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //FROZENCA_MATRIXVIEW_H
```

MatrixInitializer.h

```
#ifndef FROZENCA_MATRIXINITIALIZER_H
#define FROZENCA_MATRIXINITIALIZER_H

#include <concepts>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace frozenca {

template <std::regular T, std::size_t N>
struct MatrixInitializer {
    using type = std::initializer_list<typename MatrixInitializer<T, N - 1>::type>;
};

template <std::regular T>
struct MatrixInitializer<T, 1> {
    using type = std::initializer_list<T>;
};

template <std::regular T>
struct MatrixInitializer<T, 0>;

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //FROZENCA_MATRIXINITIALIZER_H
```

MatrixUtils.h

```
#ifndef FROZENCA_MATRIXUTILS_H
#define FROZENCA_MATRIXUTILS_H

#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace frozenca {

template <typename... Args>
inline constexpr bool All(Args... args) { return (... && args); };

template <typename... Args>
inline constexpr bool Some(Args... args) { return (... || args); };

template <typename... Args>
concept RequestingElement = All(std::is_convertible_v<Args, std::size_t>...);

template <std::size_t N>
std::array<std::size_t, N> computeStrides(const std::array<std::size_t, N>& dims) {
    std::array<std::size_t, N> strides;
    std::size_t str = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
        strides[i] = str;
        str *= dims[i];
    }
    return strides;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Initializer>
bool checkNonJagged(const Initializer& init) {
    auto i = std::cbegin(init);
    for (auto j = std::next(i); j != std::cend(init); ++j) {
        if (i->size() != j->size()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Iter, typename Initializer>
void addDims(Iter& first, const Initializer& init) {
    if constexpr (N > 1) {
        assert(checkNonJagged<N>(init));
    }
    *first = std::size(init);
    ++first;
    if constexpr (N > 1) {
        addDims<N - 1>(first, *std::begin(init));
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Initializer>
std::array<std::size_t, N> deriveDims(const Initializer& init) {
    std::array<std::size_t, N> dims;
    auto f = std::begin(dims);
    addDims<N>(f, init);
    return dims;
}

template <std::regular T>
void addList(std::unique_ptr<T[]>& data,
             const T* first, const T* last,
             std::size_t& index) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        data[index] = *first;
        ++index;
    }
}

template <std::regular T, typename I>
void addList(std::unique_ptr<T[]>& data,
             const std::initializer_list<I>* first, const std::initializer_list<I>* last,
             std::size_t& index) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        addList(data, first->begin(), first->end(), index);
    }
}

template <std::regular T, typename I>
void insertFlat(std::unique_ptr<T[]>& data, std::initializer_list<I> list) {
    std::size_t index = 0;
    addList(data, std::begin(list), std::end(list), index);
}

inline long quot(long a, long b) {
    return (a % b) >= 0 ? (a / b) : (a / b) - 1;
}

inline long mod(long a, long b) {
    return (a % b + b) % b;
}

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //FROZENCA_MATRIXUTILS_H
```

Test code:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    frozenca::Matrix<float, 2> m {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    m = {{4, 6}, {1, 3}};
    std::cout << m(1, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << m[{1, 1}] << '\n';

    // 3 x 4 x 5
    frozenca::Matrix<int, 3> m2 (3, 4, 5);
    std::iota(std::begin(m2), std::end(m2), 0);

    // should output 0 ~ 59
    for (auto n : m2) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto sub = m2.submatrix({1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 4});

    // 26 27 28
    // 31 32 33
    for (auto n : sub) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

Works as intended.

Yet to come: Custom allocators, slices, numerical operations (ex. matrix multiplication), reshape(), 1-D template specialization, etc.

Feel free to comment anything as always!

Comment: It looks like you know what you're doing.  My only issue reading it is design comments (lack of): in particular, why is `T` being passed to the base class template?  It's like a mystery novel, learning that after reading a while, rather than being told the architecture up front.

Comment: @JDługosz The use of ```T``` in ```MatrixBase``` is to use CRTP pattern, which enables several member functions (```begin()``` and friends, ```operator()(size_t, ...)```) to be polymorphic without declaring them as ```virtual```.

Comment: So call it "ConcreteClass" or somesuch, not `T`, and put `//CRTP` as a comment after it.

Comment: Sure, this is not (yet) intended to be used by others, but I have to document APIs to improve this later.

Comment: I'm not sure if locality would increase (or if it's relevant) if you changed `std::array<std::size_t, N> dims_; std::array<std::size_t, N> strides_;` to `std::array<extent, N>` where class extent contains both dims_ and structs_. This would also allow moving some member functions to the class (where they make sense.)

Answer (score 7):

This is looking very good. I especially like the improvement of `submatrix()`. Still, there are a few things I mentioned in my review of the 2D class that I'll repeat here, as well as add a few other remarks.

## Avoid restricting template types too much

I see you are using `std::regular` now instead of `concept Scalar`. This still requires that the type is equality comparable, but nothing in your classes depend on that. You could perhaps use [`std::semiregular`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/semiregular) instead.

## Avoid code duplication

Always look for opportunities to reduce code duplication, even if it looks like small stuff. In `MatrixBase`, `begin()` and related functions all do a `static_cast<T&>(*this)`. You can make this code look nicer by writing:

```
template <typename T, std::semiregular R, std::size_t N>
class MatrixBase {
    T &self() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
    ...
public:
    auto begin() { return self().begin(); }
    ...
}
```

`quot()` in MatrixUtils.h could be rewritten as:

```
inline long quot(long a, long b) {
    return (a / b) - (a % b < 0);
}
```

Removing duplication reduces the chance of bugs.

## Issues with `concept RequestingElement`

This concept is used in variadic templates, but it should not itself be a variadic template. I would rewrite it as:

```
template <typename Arg>
concept RequestingElement = std::is_convertible_v<Arg, std::size_t>;
```

With this, the concepts `All` and `Some` are not necessary. However, there are more issues with this concept. For example, this just checks that something is implicitly convertible to `size_t`, but a `float` would also implicitly convert to a `size_t`. It would be better to restrict this to [`integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral) types.

Finally, the name is is not very clear to me, I think it would be better to rename this to `IndexType`.

## Make `size_`, `dims_` and `strides_` `const`

It looks like the dimensions of a matrix are fixed at construction time. You should therefore make the member variables that represent the size and shape of the matrix `const`.

Note that you can, and will need to, call functions inside the member initializer list, like so for example:

```
template <typename T, std::regular R, std::size_t N>
template <typename... Dims>
MatrixBase<T, R, N>::MatrixBase(Dims... dims) :
    size_{(... * static_cast<std::size_t>(dims))},
    dims_{static_cast<std::size_t>(dims)...},
    strides_{computeStrides(dims_)},
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Dims) == N);
}
```

## Allow zero length dimensions

It looks like your code handles matrices with one of the dimensions having length zero just fine. I would remove the check for that in the constructor of `MatrixBase`.

Note that allocating an array of length zero using `new`, and by extension also when using `std::make_unique<T[]>(size)`, is legal in C++.

Comment: If you have `const` data members, then you can't assign to the object.  He's also defining `swap`.

Comment: Ah, good point. I guess it depends then on whether you want to allow swapping between matrices of different sizes. It already limits swapping to matrices with the same number of dimensions...

Comment: Although constructing zero-length dimension matrix itself isn't illegal, you can't do anything meaningful with matrix that contains zero-length dimension (almost all operations will throw exceptions). That's why I didn't allow zero-length dimensions.

Comment: Also I moved ```submatrix()``` to ```MatrixBase```, because we can make submatrix from view of matrix as well. Other operations like matrix addition and multiplication will be done upon ```MatrixBase```! Cool!

Comment: @frozenca "you can't do anything meaningful with matrix that contains zero-length dimension" - you might want to look at why Fortran (from Fortran 90 through to the latest version) allows zero-length dimensions to be used with the obvious semantics and no exceptions thrown. The basic reason is because they are *useful!*

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 you can count on `/` and `%` behaving in a prescribed manner:  Rather than being implementation-defined (whatever the underlying machine instruction does), it is defined to truncate toward zero.  So, you don't need your `quot` wrapper, and `mod` can likewise assume that division worked that way already.

And before C++11, there was `std::div`.

---

```
 auto f = std::begin(dims);
```

You need to invoke `begin` and a few others by using the "`std` two-step", not by calling the qualified version directly.  If the type of `dims` is not a built-in, and requires argument-dependant lookup, then this will fail.

```
using std::begin;
auto f = begin(dims);
```

or, use the newer versions in the `ranges` namespace, or your own wrappers.

But you know the type is `std::array`, so just like you did when you had an `std::initializer_list`, just use the member function form `dims.begin()` so it doesn't raise red flags to the reader.

---

BTW, `#pragma once;` works on all the major compilers.

Comment: ```quot``` and ```mod``` behave differently with ```/``` and ```%```. ```quot(-7, 4) = -2```, ```mod(-7, 4) = 1```, ```-7 / 4 = -1```, ```-7 % 4 = -3```. Also I don't like ```#pragma once```, it is non-standard.