# View of submatrix, in const and non-const form, preserving const-correctness

Tags: c++, c++20

Here are implementations of both non-const and const view of submatrices,
which is a subclass of my toy C++ matrix project: ([C++20 : N-dimensional minimal Matrix class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260197/c20-n-dimensional-minimal-matrix-class))

MatrixView.h

```
template <std::semiregular T, std::size_t N, bool Const>
class MatrixView final : public MatrixBase<MatrixView<T, N, Const>, T, N> {
public:
    using Base = MatrixBase<MatrixView<T, N, Const>, T, N>;
    using Base::size;
    using Base::dims;
    using Base::strides;
    using Base::applyFunction;
    using Base::applyFunctionWithBroadcast;
    using Base::operator=;
    using Base::operator+=;
    using Base::operator-=;
    using Base::operator*=;
    using Base::operator/=;
    using Base::operator%=;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, const T&, T&>;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using pointer = std::conditional_t<Const, const T*, T*>;
    using stride_type = std::array<std::size_t, N>;

private:
    pointer data_view_;
    stride_type orig_strides_;

public:
    ~MatrixView() noexcept = default;

    explicit MatrixView(const stride_type& dims, pointer data_view, const stride_type& orig_strides);

    template <typename DerivedOther>
    MatrixView(const MatrixBase<DerivedOther, T, N>& other);

    template <typename DerivedOther, std::semiregular U> requires std::is_convertible_v<U, T>
    MatrixView& operator=(const MatrixBase<DerivedOther, U, N>& other) requires (!Const);

    friend void swap(MatrixView& a, MatrixView& b) noexcept {
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
        std::swap(a.data_view_, b.data_view_);
        std::swap(a.orig_strides_, b.orig_strides_);
    }


    template <bool IterConst>
    struct MVIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = std::conditional_t<(Const || IterConst), const T*, T*>;
        using reference = std::conditional_t<(Const || IterConst), const T&, T&>;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using MatViewType = std::conditional_t<(Const || IterConst), const MatrixView*, MatrixView*>;

        MatViewType ptr_ = nullptr;
        std::array<std::size_t, N> pos_ = {0};
        std::size_t offset_ = 0;
        std::size_t index_ = 0;

        MVIterator() = default;

        MVIterator(MatViewType ptr, std::array<std::size_t, N> pos = {0}) : ptr_ {ptr}, pos_ {pos} {
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        reference operator*() const {
            return ptr_->data_view_[offset_];
        }

        pointer operator->() const {
            return ptr_->data_view_ + offset_;
        }

        void ValidateOffset() {
            offset_ = std::inner_product(std::cbegin(pos_), std::cend(pos_), std::cbegin(ptr_->origStrides()), 0lu);
            index_ = std::inner_product(std::cbegin(pos_), std::cend(pos_), std::cbegin(ptr_->strides()), 0lu);
            assert(index_ <= ptr_->size());
        }

        void Increment() {
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                ++pos_[i];
                if (pos_[i] != ptr_->dims(i) || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    pos_[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Increment(std::ptrdiff_t n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                Decrement(-n);
                return;
            }
            auto carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(n);
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                std::size_t curr_dim = ptr_->dims(i);
                pos_[i] += carry;
                if (pos_[i] < curr_dim || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    carry = pos_[i] / curr_dim;
                    pos_[i] %= curr_dim;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Decrement() {
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                --pos_[i];
                if (pos_[i] != static_cast<std::size_t>(-1) || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    pos_[i] = ptr_->dims(i) - 1;
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        void Decrement(std::ptrdiff_t n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                Increment(-n);
                return;
            }
            auto carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(n);
            for (std::size_t i = N - 1; i < N; --i) {
                std::size_t curr_dim = ptr_->dims(i);
                pos_[i] -= carry;
                if (pos_[i] < curr_dim || i == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    carry = static_cast<std::size_t>(-quot(static_cast<long>(pos_[i]), static_cast<long>(curr_dim)));
                    pos_[i] = mod(static_cast<long>(pos_[i]), static_cast<long>(curr_dim));
                }
            }
            ValidateOffset();
        }

        MVIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator++(int) {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator--(int) {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator operator+(difference_type n) const {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            temp.Increment(n);
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator+=(difference_type n) {
            Increment(n);
            return *this;
        }

        MVIterator operator-(difference_type n) const {
            MVIterator temp = *this;
            temp.Decrement(n);
            return temp;
        }

        MVIterator& operator-=(difference_type n) {
            Decrement(n);
            return *this;
        }

        reference operator[](difference_type n) const {
            return *(*this + n);
        }

        template <bool IterConstOther>
        difference_type operator-(const MVIterator<IterConstOther>& other) const {
            return index_ - other.index_;
        }

    };

    template <bool IterConst>
    friend bool operator==(const MVIterator<IterConst>& it1, const MVIterator<IterConst>& it2) {
        return it1.ptr_ == it2.ptr_ && it1.index_ == it2.index_;
    }

    template <bool IterConst>
    friend bool operator!=(const MVIterator<IterConst>& it1, const MVIterator<IterConst>& it2) {
        return !(it1 == it2);
    }

    template <bool IterConst1, bool IterConst2>
    friend auto operator<=>(const MVIterator<IterConst1>& it1, const MVIterator<IterConst2>& it2) {
        return it1.pos_ <=> it2.pos_;
    }

    using iterator = MVIterator<Const>;
    using const_iterator = MVIterator<true>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    iterator begin() { return iterator(this);}
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(this, {dims(0), });}
    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(this, {dims(0), });}
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(this, {dims(0), });}
    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());}
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cend());}
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cend());}
    reverse_iterator rend() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());}
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cbegin());}
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(cbegin());}

    [[nodiscard]] pointer dataView() const {
        return data_view_;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const stride_type& origStrides() const {
        return orig_strides_;
    }

    MatrixView& operator-() {
        Base::Base::operator-();
        return *this;
    }

};
```

MatrixBase.h

```
template <typename Derived, std::semiregular T, std::size_t N>
class MatrixBase : public ObjectBase<MatrixBase<Derived, T, N>> {
    static_assert(N > 1);
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t ndim = N;
    using extent_type = std::array<std::size_t, N>;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using view_type = MatrixView<T, N, false>;
    using const_view_type = MatrixView<T, N, true>;
    using row_type = MatrixView<T, N - 1, false>;
    using const_row_type = MatrixView<T, N - 1, true>;

// ... details ...

    view_type submatrix(const extent_type& pos_begin);
    view_type submatrix(const extent_type& pos_begin, const extent_type& pos_end);
    row_type row(std::size_t n);
    row_type col(std::size_t n);
    row_type operator[](std::size_t n) { return row(n); }

    const_view_type submatrix(const extent_type& pos_begin) const;
    const_view_type submatrix(const extent_type& pos_begin, const extent_type& pos_end) const;
    const_row_type row(std::size_t n) const;
    const_row_type col(std::size_t n) const;
    const_row_type operator[](std::size_t n) const { return row(n); }

// ... details ...
};

// N == 1 specialization
template <typename Derived, std::semiregular T>
class MatrixBase<Derived, T, 1> : public ObjectBase<MatrixBase<Derived, T, 1>> {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t ndim = 1;
    using extent_type = std::array<std::size_t, 1>;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using view_type = MatrixView<T, 1, false>;
    using const_view_type = MatrixView<T, 1, true>;
    using row_type = reference;
    using const_row_type = const_reference;
// ... details ...
};
```

Maintaining const-correctness correctly is extremely tedious and tricky. I posted code only relevant to techniques implementating const and non-const iterators and views. If you're interested in the full code, you can visit https://github.com/frozenca/Ndim-Matrix

Feel free to comment anything!

Answer (score 2):

## Unnecessary use of `using`

You are publicly inheriting from `MatrixBase<...>`, so there is usually no need to use `using Base::...` to explicitly bring member functions and operator overloads into the derived class. The only reason to do this is if you are providing an overload of such a member function in the derived class with different arguments types, and still want the version from base to be available as well (by default it would be [hidden](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule)).

I would strongly recommend removing the redundant `using`s, it makes it seem like there is something special going on when there's not, and it's just a lot of work to maintain for no gain at all.

## Maintaining const-correctness

> Maintaining const-correctness correctly is extremely tedious and tricky.

Indeed, it is a bit tedious. However, you can reduce the amount of code you need to write somewhat. First, instead of duplicating the whole body of a member function you need to make const and non-const overloads for, just have one with the full body, and others call the full version where possible. For example, an easy case is this:

```
const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
```

It would also help if `iterator` didn't have a `bool` template parameter, but could automatically detect if it should be `const` or not. Perhaps this makes things simpler:

```
template <MatViewType>
requires std::same_as<std::remove_cv_t<MatViewType>, MatrixView>
struct MVIterator {
    constexpr bool IterConst = std::is_const_v<MatViewType>;
    using std::conditional_t<Const || IterConst, const T*, T*>;
    ...
    MatViewType *ptr_{};
    ...
    MVIterator(MatViewType *ptr, ...): ptr_{ptr} {...}
    ...
};
```

With that, `iterator(this)` would automatically get you a const iterator if `this` is `const`.

Perhaps `MatrixView` itself could determine in a similar way if it's const or not, based on whether `pointer data_view` is `const` or not.

Comment: "The explicit keyword only has an effect on constructors that take exactly one argument." I don't think that's true though? It prevents implicit conversions like `return { blah, blah, blah };` which one might want to avoid.

Comment: @user673679 You are right. Although normally I would not think that is something you want to avoid (it only works if the return type is known in advance and it's clear you are going to construct a new object of that type), since there's inheritance involved here, it might indeed be better to keep the `explicit` to avoid surprises.

Comment: There is also a use for "redundant" using if the base-class depends on a template-argument, so you can use the name in the derived class. Not that that is the case for most of them here.